# DIV positioning and overlay

Tags: html, css, overlay

I have this structure:

```
<div id="container">

  <div id="div1">A BIG TITLE HERE</div>

  <div id="nestDiv">
    <div id="div2"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png" /></div>
    <div id="div3">over</div>
  </div>   

</div>
```

I´m triying to place div3 over div2 without results. Please, review the test in the link:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiourra/wddowj8a/2/)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have an extra closing curly brace at line 21. Just remove it and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, indeed (and sorry). Maybe I must never stay up all night again.

Comment: Just a typo: http://jsfiddle.net/wddowj8a/4/

Comment: Thasks Danijel and dcc. :)